# System.IO.IOException: file used by another process when try to write to file

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I searched over the internet and saw many questions about it, i tried many suggestion solutions, but nothing seems to work for me (maybe i am not implementing something right)

Here is my aspx.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public partial class Default : Page
{
    static List<Member> memberList = new List<Member>();
    static string fileName = @"C:\Users\Nir - PC\Desktop\public\gradesClient.json";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            using (StreamReader re = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(re);
                JsonSerializer se = new JsonSerializer();
                object parsedData = se.Deserialize(reader);
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedData);

                Console.Write(json);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        memberList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Member>>(File.ReadAllText(fileName));

        Member member = new Member();

        member.id = 4;
        member.name = name.Value;
        member.email = email.Value;
        member.Date = date.Value;
        member.Address = address.Value;
        member.Country = country.Value;
        member.Zip = zip.Value;
        member.Grade = Int32.Parse(grade.Value);
        member.Course = course.Value;

        memberList.Add(member);

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(memberList.ToArray());
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, json);
    }
}


public class Member
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }

    public Member()
    {

    }
}
```

the error happens when it reach to line `File.WriteAllText(fileName, json);`

Please help me to fix the problem,
Please provide example code.

Thanks

Comment: close your `JsonReader reader`

Comment: this is maybe a stupid question but... how do i close it?

Comment: and please, change your code, don't use `object` as target type for a json deserialization. you already have your class structure (Member). `var member = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Member>(File.ReadAllText(fileName));

Comment: you can close using the close method on the reader object. refer [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) for the API documentation. it implements Dispose as well. so you can wrap it in using block also.

Comment: try to call Close() ? https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs#L2400

Comment: @Izzy No, unfortunately it won´t. Close your streamreader also. it keeps your file locked / in use

Comment: @Radinator i can't use override because there is nothing to override for... i tried to call `reader.Close();` under the `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedData);`, it did not solve the problem...

Comment: Please give it a try to call re.Close() too

Comment: @Izzy what do you mean by reference? I encountered thsi problem to with streamreader, filereader or "whateverreader" and I found out, that the reader keeps the file in use until you close it manually...

Comment: @MarcelTheis tried re.Close() too, still not solve the problem.

Comment: inside your `Page_Load` event put your code inside `if(!IsPostBack){// code here}`

Comment: Thank you guys, i closed the solution and opened again after edit `reader.Close()` and `re.Close()`, seems to work now. :)

Comment: Note that you could still occasionally get a file locking issue unless you use some form of thread locking/synchrononization to avoid File.WriteAllText being called whilst another thread is in the Page_Load handler.